# is it possible to automatically download Prerequisites using wix bootstrapper

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7, bootstrapper, prerequisites

I have created a setup using wix and have even created customized dialogs too.Now i need mySetup to auto download the  Prerequisites for my application.Seems it can be done through bootstrapper only.I have even created a bootstrapper file too,but I don't want to attach Prerequisites setup **(ie) .exe** files in bootstrapper for installing the  Prerequisites .Instead i need to  **download the directly from web and need to install automatically**   when my setup runs.

is it possible with wix ??  Am new to wix and if its possible please share me some source ??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Simply use SourceFile to avoid any inconvenience.

```
<ExePackage 
              Id="InstallJava"
              DetectCondition='NOT Installed AND JAVACURRENTVERSION>="1.6"'
              InstallCondition='NOT VersionNT64'
              SourceFile="..\dep\jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe"  
              InstallCommand='/s'
              Compressed="no"
              Permanent="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Vital="no"
              DownloadUrl="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=86895"
              />
```

Download the prereq.exe and use SourceFile attribute to refer it. WiX will automatically calculate the Hashcode, etc.

But if you are more inclined toward using RemotePayLoad then use heat.exe to harvest this data.

```
<wix-folder>/bin/heat payload d:\prereq.exe -out d:\remote.xml
```

Comment: which location will the auto downloaded file will be?

Comment: can you please tell me hoe to use heat

Comment: @user3611781 Download the package (like prereq.exe) which you want to harvest. Then use the command which I had mentioned in my answer. You could find heat.exe under WIX installation folder C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7. Open remote.xml in text editor for RemotePayload info.

Comment: @user3611781  WIX will automatically download and installed the prerequisite. You don't have to take care about download location. You could use **InstallCommand** for additional params to pass.

Answer (score 0):

[EXEPACKAGE](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) - you can make use of the DownloadUrl attribute.

> DownloadUrl - The URL to use to download the package. The following
>   substitutions are supported: {0} is replaced by the package Id. {1} is
>   replaced by the payload Id. {2} is replaced by the payload file name.
>
> [RemotePayload](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/remotepayload.html) - Describes information about a remote file payload
>   that is not available at the time of building the bundle. The parent
>   must specify DownloadUrl and must not specify SourceFile when using
>   this element.

For example:

```
<PackageGroup 
            Id="Netfx4Full">
            <ExePackage 
                Id="Netfx4Full" 
                Cache="no" 
                Compressed="no" 
                PerMachine="yes" 
                Permanent="yes" 
                Vital="yes"
                DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" >

             <RemotePayload
               ProductName="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" 
                Description="Dotnet 4.0"
                Size="3961856" 
                Version="4.0.5022.0" />
             </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
```

Comment: seems here also we need to add source file (ie) required .exe file with our solution.??

Comment: if the required  setup have already installed in the system means what will happen.? @Isaiah4110

Comment: add InstallCondition attribute within the ExePackage element.

Comment: i am really new to wix?can you please guide me ?

Comment: The required setup would obviously create some registry entries right? In the install condition check for those registry entries. If it exists, you dont need to install otherwise you do. I am guiding you as much as I can, and I think you have enough information above to work this out.

Comment: :ya you're right am asking how to put that condition here

Comment: @Isaish4110 can you please tell me how to find the hash value for remotePayLoad.?

Comment: @lsaish4110can you help me out in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059892/how-to-insert-a-image-in-setup-dialog-in-wix-installer