# How to insert a Groupbox and image in setup dialog in wix Installer

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

Am developing an installer for my application using wix installer.installer. Wix is really new to me .
In that installer am having a custom  dialog and where i have kept check boxes inside it.

```
 <Control Id="InstallWORD" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="200" Width="200" Height="17" Property="INSTALLWORD" CheckBoxValue="1"
           Text="Install Word Plug-In?" />
```

the above is the code i used for keeping check box. But now i need to insert a small picture near the checkbox (ie)
similar like this
[image]

how to make it possible in wix installer??

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add a Binary element to the file:

```
<Binary Id="MainImage" SourceFile="Resources/Images/weblabel.jpg" />
```

...and to set the Text of the Bitmap Control to "MainImage":

```
        <Control Id="Bitmap"
                    Type="Bitmap"
                    X="0"
                    Y="0"
                    Width="258"
                    Height="185"
                    TabSkip="no"
                    Text="MainImage" />
```

and for adding a group box

```
    <Control Id="grpBox"  Type="GroupBox"   X="8" Y="50" Width="355" Height="210" Text="Add-in for Microsoft Office" ></Control>
```

and now it works. :)